# Mixing in a path dependent trait

Tags: scala, mixins, traits, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

So have these various traits that I want to mixin to a base class called GPState (Genetic Programming State). Some of the things I want to mixin however depend on things I wont know until the GPState is being constructed. Hence I am using scala's path dependency feature.

Say my path dependent trait looks something like this

```
case class HasTermGen[...](depths : Seq[Int], widths : Seq[Int]) {
  trait gen extends GPState[...] {
    override def genInitTerm(): Term = {
      <...some stuff here depending on 'depths' and 'widths'...>
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I want to construct a GPState I want to be able to do something like this

```
val gpstate = new GPState[Var, Type, Term, Double] 
              with <...some mixin...>
              <...some other mixins that do other stuff...>
              with HasTermGen[...](3 to 7, 4 to 9).gen
```

But this appears to be a syntax error. I can do it if I define a varible first

```
val hasTermGen = HasTermGen[...](3 to 7, 4 to 9)
val gpstate = new GPState[Var, Type, Term, Double] 
              with <...some mixin...>
              <...some other mixins that do other stuff...>
              with hasTermGen.gen
```

But this looks a tad on the ugly side.

I'm willing to give up on this specific syntax and even using a class like 'HasTermGen' and many other things. What I really need is to be able to create an object which implements the methods of GPState in a particular fashion based on information defined at the construction site. Additionally it is likely that the means of implementing these methods will have some common elements (data wise) they will want to utilize so that needs to be accounted for as well. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your trait `GPState` in dependent on the instances of `HasTermGen`.

```
val myTermGen = HasTermGen[...](3 to 7, 4 to 9)
val myState = new myTermGen[...] { ... }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to convey here. Mind explaining a bit more?